# Why don't woked Enable-Migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget, entity-framework-4.3

I create asp.net mvc3 project, install entity framework 4.3.1 from nuget.

next

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
```

and get error:

> System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException: Unable to find type [System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsCommands]: Make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
>           in System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError (ErrorRecord errorRecord)
>       Can not find type [System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsCommands]: Make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

Comment: Duplicate: [Entity Framework Migrations Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575628/entity-framework-migrations-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete or update .net reflector